# passing a reference as a parameter to a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function which allocates memory for a given class and calls its constructor.
For example:

```
template <class T, class arg0>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(a0); }
template <class T, class arg0, class arg1>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0, arg1 a1) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(a0,a1); }
```

It works fine when I pass anything by value or a pointer, like:

```
int myInt = 5;
int* myIntPointer = &myInt;

MyClass1* myCls1 = AllocateObject<MyClass1>(myInt);     // a class with int in its constructor
MyClass2* myCls2 = AllocateObject<MyClass2>(myIntPointer);    // a class with int ptr in its constructor
```

however it dosn't work when I try to pass anything by reference, like

```
int& myIntRef = myInt;

MyClass3* myCls3 = AllocateObject<MyClass3>(myIntRef, myIntRef);     // a class with two int ref in its constructor
```

When I try to do that I get errors like:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template
error C2780: 'T *IMemoryAllocator::AllocateObject(arg0)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
```

..even though the MyClass3 constructor accepts two arguments, and the template should then choose the version with 2 arguments. It's like the template dosn't know which function to choose.

Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing `MyClass3* myCls3 = AllocateObject<MyClass3>(myIntRef, myIntRef);` to `MyClass3* myCls3 = AllocateObject<MyClass3, int, int>(myIntRef, myIntRef);`?

Answer (score -1):

Try `std::remove_reference` template.

```
template <class T, class arg0>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(std::remove_reference<arg0>::type(a0)); }
```

or, even in more c++'er way using `static_cast`:

```
template <class T, class arg0>
inline T* AllocateObject(arg0 a0) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(static_cast<std::remove_reference<arg0>::type>(a0)); }
```